# if I have $n$-bit binary number $x$, if add 1 at its $m$-bit ($m>n$), how would the counterpart base-10 number change?

Tags: binary

If $x$ (base-10) is an $n$-bits number in binary, such as $(x)_{10}=\underbrace{11\cdots 1}_{n\text{}}$, if I add $1$ in $m$-bit position, it becomes $(y)_{10}=\underbrace{10\cdots0011\cdots 1}_{m\text{}}$. What is the formula relating $y$ and $x$?

Comment: The notation is misleading. Why $(x)_{10}$ when it is in binary?

Comment: If you add $1$ in the $m$-bit position then $y=x+2^{m+1}$.

Comment: @Chrystomath:  you should specify if you start counting with $0$ (because of the exponent) or $1$ (because we often do.)  If you start from $1$ it is $2^{m-1}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Of course, my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ are numbers irrespective of what base you represent them in.  What is constant as you change bases is the value, not the representation.  The form you give for $x$ is the binary form.  The subscript $2$ should go on the right to indicate that.  $x$ does not need a subscript as you have not committed to what base it is represented in.

You can write $13_{10}=1101_2$.  These are two different representations of the same number.  If we start counting the bits from $1$ and put a $1$ in the $m^{th}$ place, that bit is worth $2^{m-1}$ and we are  adding that much to our number.  In this example, for $m=7$ we get $1001101_2=77_{10}$.  We have added $2^{6}=64_{10}=1000000_2$